# Dependency of $\mu_r$ vs $B$ of ferromagnetic material

Tags: ferromagnetism

How $\mu_r$ will change in a specimen of ferromagnetic material as the flux density is increased from $0$ to $2.5T$ ? [Given: Saturation Magnetisation of the ferromagnetic material is $8000$ Gauss]

My Thoughts:
We know ferromagnetic material obey hysteresis curve
and $10^4$ Gauss $=1T$
$\therefore 8000$ Gauss $=0.8T$
so,
[image]
We also know: $$B= \mu_0(H+M)$$
so from the hysteresis curve,
$1)$ As $B$ is increased from $0T$ to a certain value ($<2.5T$), such that $M=0.8T$; $H$ and $M$ both will increase
Let us denote this certain value as $B_c$
$2)$ And as $B$ is further increased from $B_c$ to $2.5T$, $M$ will saturates and changes in $B$ will be reflected in $H$ ;thus only $H$ will increase now

we also know: $$M= \chi_M \times H$$ where $\chi_M=$ magentic susceptibility of the material
$$\implies M= (\mu_r - 1) \times H$$
$$\implies H= \frac{M}{\mu_r -1}$$
so when $M$ saturates and $H$ is increasing to $\infty$ ; then $\mu_r$ is tending towards $1$
and we know for ferromagnetic materials: $\mu_r>>1$
**Thus we conclude in case$2$ (as $B$ is further increased from $B_c$ to $2.5T$) ; $\mu_r$ decreases**

Now i am not getting any conclusion about $\mu_r$ in case$1$? so any hints or suggestions please.....

Comment: The permeability of a material changes with the amount of magnetic flux forced through it. If you have a sheet steel the curve will be higher

Comment: You didn't get my question;i mean whether $\mu_r$ will increase throughout $0T$ to $2.5T$;or $\mu_r$ will increase first and then decrease ;or $\mu_r$ will decrease first and then increase or $\mu_r$ will only decrease

Comment: It wil increase the stay constant just like the letter S

Comment: Increase 0 ----> 2,5 T    very slow increase 2,5T ----> inf (magnetic saturation)

Comment: In a ferromagnetic (or *any* magnetic) material $B$ can never saturate, instead what saturates is $M$, where $B=\mu_0 (H+M)$. While $\mu_r$ is not a very useful concept for ferromagnets, but if you must use it then $\mu_r \rightarrow 1$ as $H \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Can you relate  $\mu_r$  in my first case (case$1$) ?; besides your comment was really valuable but due to my low reputation I could not vote up your comment @hyportnex

Comment: I admit I have difficulty understanding your question but here is a hint to what I think you are asking: you know that when $B=2.5T$ the magnetization is saturated and is $\mu_0 M_s=0.8T$, therefore $B- \mu_0 M_s=\mu_0H = 1.7T$, so then you have to calculate $B/(\mu_0 H)$...